# Error in namespace when fitting basic regression in rstan

Tags: r, regression, stan

I'm trying to fit a basic model in rstan and I get this error:

**Error:**

```
TRANSLATING MODEL 'model_code' FROM Stan CODE TO C++ CODE NOW.
Error in .Call("CPP_stanc260", model_code, model_cppname) : 
  "CPP_stanc260" not resolved from current namespace (rstan)
```

**Traceback:**

```
> traceback()
4: .Call("CPP_stanc260", model_code, model_cppname)
3: stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name, 
       verbose, ...)
2: stan_model(file, model_name = model_name, model_code = model_code, 
       boost_lib = boost_lib, eigen_lib = eigen_lib, save_dso = save_dso, 
       verbose = verbose, ...)
1: stan(model_code = model_code, data = LC_stan_data, iter = 1000, 
       chains = 4)
```

**Full Code:**

```
> log_bid_price_sample
 [1] 7.025538 6.437752 6.684612 5.857933 5.298317 4.382027 4.605170 4.605170 5.521461 7.090077 5.164786
[12] 6.856462 3.401197 7.090077 5.703782 3.911823 6.214608 6.214608 5.703782 5.703782

LC_stan_data <- list(N = 20,
                     log_bid_price = log_bid_price[1:20],
                     lawncare_needs = rnorm(20, mean = log_bid_price, sd = 10))

model_code = "
data {
  int <lower=0> N;
  real log_bid_price[N];
  real lawncare_needs[N];
}
parameters{
  real beta[1];
  real <lower = 0> sigma;
}
model {
  log_bid_price ~ normal(beta*Lawncare_needs, sigma)
}
"

fit <- stan(model_code = model_code, data = LC_stan_data,
            iter = 1000, chains = 4)
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: We don't know, but you are not the first person to have encountered it. I would suggest trying to restart R (making sure that a `.RData` file is not autoloaded that contains objects created by a previous version of rstan), then doing `remove.packages("rstan")` and then reinstalling rstan. Hopefully the problem will go away this week when rstan gets uploaded to CRAN.